# Can I Use the YouTube API for My Website's Feature Based on My Current Situation?

Tags: youtube-api

I would like to know if I can use the YouTube API without violating its terms based on my current situation. Here are the details:

- I am planning to develop a feature using the YouTube API.
- The website I am developing for is already live and generates revenue through advertisements.
- The feature using the YouTube API is just one of many on my website, and the main functionality of my site does not rely on the YouTube API.
- The specific feature I want to implement allows users to register their own YouTube videos on my - website, making them viewable by other users. Additionally, users can "like" the YouTube videos displayed on my site.
- I intend to use the YouTube API to verify if the videos belong to the users registering them.

Can you confirm if this usage aligns with the YouTube API's terms and conditions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it about licensing / contracts / legal matters and not a programming problem.

Answer (score -1):

With the YouTube API you can do what you specified. You can have to implement a client authentication for every user of your website and then use the access token of the google user to manage their data. For example to check whether the user have a YouTube channel, list their videos, read comments and the user can upload video to YouTube from your website and they can query their YouTube Contents to their account associated with your website.
But keep in mind that you have to publish you google API client project before your users can use it. In development purpose you can add at most 12 users in testing purpose.